# Two columns with variable width and a fixed gap between them

Tags: css, html

I need to style two columns dynamically. They should have a width of 50% each, but a fixed gap of 10px between them.

When I collapse my menu the columns should widen to the space available and the gap should remain 10px. Because of this a can't take a fixed width for the columns.

I tried this:

```css
#container {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 -5px;
}
.column {
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#left {
  background: green;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
#right {
  background: blue;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
#space {
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px; border:1px solid black">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="column"></div>
    <div id="space"></div>
    <div id="right" class="column"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But then the blue and the green divs expand over the outer div with the black border.

[This is what it should look like](http://jsfiddle.net/p59vJ/9/). Any chance that i can set a relative height for the columns or am i forced to use javascript when collapsing my menu?

Comment: do you have some code already?

Comment: you said dynamically but didn't tag this as javascript.

Comment: Can you expand on "when I collapse my menu" so that we can get an idea of what's actually moving around on the page and how it's moving?  Are you looking for a pure-CSS solution or can some JavaScript be tossed in the mix?

Comment: I look for a pure css solution. My menu is on the left side and I can collapse it so only the active menu item is visible. The content-div of the page then expands to the full width of the side. The columns should expand, too.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the collapsing / expanding will require javascript

Comment: Yes it does, but width of the content-div (in the example the one with the black border) is not my problem. The problem is styling the inner columns divs (blue and green) and when there's a possibility to do this with css I would prefer that.

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/p59vJ/4/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need either tables or CSS tables.

[CSS tables should be supported by all browsers except IE7 and below.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a few months old, but I have another potential solution, which I will post here for posterity, in case it helps someone else:

What I did was snug two columns right in next to each other, and then place the *real* columns inside of those columns, using a 5px margin on each, on the shared side, to create the illusion of a 10px gap.

I have set up a demo similar to the original one Chris put up, only using this trick to create the gap between the columns.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/9eWYR/27/) of the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#left').click(function() {
    $('#left').text('').animate({
      width: '0%'
    }, 'slow');
    $('#right').animate({
      width: '98%'
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 90%
}
#left,
#right {
  border: 1px Red solid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
.halfWidthColumn {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.interiorColumn {
  border: 1px Black solid;
  background-color: White;
  height: 100%;
}
.leftSide {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  background-color: Blue;
}
.rightSide {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  background-color: Green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    Click to collapse
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="halfWidthColumn">
      <div class="interiorColumn leftSide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="halfWidthColumn">
      <div class="interiorColumn rightSide">
        When in the Course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of
        Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I am no longer using JavaScript to resize the two interior columns.  I believe this will do what was originally requested, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<style>
#container{background: red;width: 100%;height: 20px;padding: 0 -5px;}
.column{height: 20px;float: left;width: 50%;}
#left{background: green;margin-left: -5px;}
#right{background: blue;margin-right: -5px;}
#space{width: 10px;float: left;height: 20px;}
</style>
```

in html

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left" class="column"></div>
<div id="space"></div>
<div id="right" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

this works in FF

Comment: Looks nice, but when I make a div around the two columns with a fixed width (in my case the content div of my page) the inner div-columns expand over the borders of the outer div.

Comment: The trouble here is that two columns at 50% add up to 100%, and *then* then 10px spacer is added.  That's why the inner divs expand beyond the container div.

Comment: Yes thats a big problem. And I can't define something like 50%-5px for the width of each column.