# Floating two 50% width divs with a 10px margin between

Tags: html, css

I want to float a pair of fluid divs across my page, each taking up half of their container's width, but with a margin of 10px between them. I've done this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andfinally/sa53B/5/, and here's the HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.prev {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.next {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

The box-sizing rule isn't enough to make this work - the divs are more than 50% wide. In one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805150/css-two-columns-with-variable-width-and-a-fixed-gap-between-them) somebody suggested using CSS display-table. Can anyone explain how to make that work in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be 10px? Could it be a fluid unit of measure too? You could make two containers 48% wide, then give the first a margin-right of 4%.

Comment: @chipcullen that wouldnt put space between the two divs though

Comment: @EricLemos - I think it would - see http://jsfiddle.net/andfinally/sa53B/5/

Comment: For what value of `margin` do you expect `50% + margin + 50% == 100%`?

Comment: I can't show you at the moment, but this is trivial with an extra layer of element nesting. Specify widths on the outer elements, and margins on the inner ones.

Comment: Thanks all - I was hoping to be able to do 10px margin, but clearly tis impossible without calc().

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can either a) lower `50%` to `48%` and make the margin `2%` or b) use CSS3 `calc`, which is not supported everywhere, but should be an option in the near future. (Specifically, when IE8 is off the table) (See http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc for compatability)

Example using percentages: http://jsfiddle.net/sa53B/9/

```
.prev {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 2% 10px 0
}

.next {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 2%
}
```

Example using `calc`: http://jsfiddle.net/sa53B/6/

```
.prev {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 47%;
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 5px);
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
}

.next {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 47%;
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 5px);
    margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the informative answer Mooseman - I need to work with mobile browsers as well so calc is not an option for me at the moment. Percentages it is!

Comment: `calc` should have no trouble with Android 4.1+ (Chrome replaces Android browser as default) and iOS 6.0+.

Comment: Never heard of calc, kind of like an improved expression? Looks nice

Comment: @JuanMendes `calc` is great, but IE8 kills the chance to rely on it.

Comment: @Mooseman I'm OK with falling back to a percentage based margin/width in that case.

Comment: `calc` works great! Especially if you don't need to support IE 8 and 9 (which, really, why should you?)

Comment: @Avishai IE8-9 still have a couple percent worldwide http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201512-201612 So depending on your demographics it's a good idea to ensure that degradation is graceful.

Answer (score 7):

Margin will add to your containers width. If you are using a width that is based on a percentage you should set your margin value a percentage as well.

For example, if you want two 50% divs. You need to account for the margin too. In order to do so, you need to subtract the margin from the total width. If you want 1% margin left and right, thats a total of 2% you need to remove from the total width.

```
div {
float: left;
width: 48%;
margin: 0 1%;
}
```

**your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sa53B/8/**

Answer (score 3):

Recently in my task i need two float columns with 8px fixed margin between them.

So, i used border and box-sizing properties without any calc magic.

So, the solition is:

```css
.wrapper__col {
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box; // used to change box-model
   overfow: hidden; // clearfix hack
}
.wrapper__col:nth-child(odd) {
   float: left;
   border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.wrapper__col:nth-child(even) {
   float: right;
   border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="wrapper__col">1</div>
   <div class="wrapper__col">2</div>
</div>
```

So, that's all ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's late but someone might be interested in this way to fix :

Wrap the elements you wish to display in columns with divs :

```
<div class="left"><a ....></a></div>
<div class="right"><a ....></a></div>
```

And just set those styles :

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
```

Whatever the margin of divs contents it won't affect the 50% width.
I used to proceed this way before hearing of usefull css calc.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa53B/125/)

Comment: This is the better way to do this because it keeps both columns at 50%, but allows you to add whatever margin you want between the content and doesn't rely on calc(). You don't have to use a %width margin.

To add to the css to make it explicit how you get the margin:
`.left a { margin-right: 5px; }`
`.right a { margin-left: 5px; }`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not work with fixed margins.  You need to calculate using percentage margins.

Box sizing only affects padding and border space, not margin space.  So 50% + 50% =100% +5px+5px > 100%.

Use % margins and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks Michael, can only tick one answer but giving this +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, but it uses variable gap between:

**css:**

```
.left {
  float:left;
  width:59%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-color:red;
}
.right {
  float:left;
  width:39%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gkmjLfgx/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want the same 10px spacing horizontally and vertically and still have equally sized columns.

You can do this by adding a "border-left: 10px solid white" to an extra DIV inside each column and add a "margin-left: -10px" to the columns container to eat up the border of the left column.

fiddle 128psahu