# Two divs side by side 100% page width with constant space between them

Tags: html, width

I want to have two divs (floated left and right) fill up 100% of page with. But I want also always have 10px empty space between them.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="float: left">left content</div>
   <!-- here I want 10px of empty space -->
   <div style="float: right">left content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating two 50% width divs with a 10px margin between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164288/floating-two-50-width-divs-with-a-10px-margin-between)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do this is using table, and create 3 column, then define the width of the middle column.

```
<table style="width:100%;>
<tr>
<td>Left</td>
<td style="width:10px;"></td>
<td>Right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mickey_dt/mp72y88n/)**

Answer (score -2):

```css
.one {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%
}
.two {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='one'></div>
  <div class='two'></div>
</div>
```

Try this, it might help you.

Comment: This is not `10px` empty space between two divs.

Comment: does you have variable width of page or constant width ?

Comment: Please see this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa53B/6/) it's best way to do this, based on what OP wanted.