# Why is UL wider than DIV even if both are set to the same width?

Tags: html, css

**HTML code:**

```
<div>Foo</div>
<ul>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

ul {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfchah01/)

**Two questions:**

1. Why is the `ul` wider than `div` although both of them have been set to the same width?
2. How can this code be fixed such that both `ul` and `div` have the same width?

Comment: Use your browser's inspector and compare them

Answer (score 4):

Because you need to know how default box model works. By default, `padding`, `border` space is considered outside of the element and hence it adds up to your total element `width`.

[image: CSS Box Model]

<sup>Credits for Image: [w3c Box model#Box Dimensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions)</sup>

If you have an element say, 100px in width, and you have a border of 2px and padding of 20px on sides, so your total element size will be 100 + 4px (2px on each side) + 40px (20px of padding on each side), that sums up to 144px in width.

---

**How do you fix this?**

Either you need to alter your box model like,

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What this thing will do is, by setting `border-box` as the `box-model` value, it will count the `padding` and `border` inside of your element instead of outside. So the total `width` of your element remains the same.

> Note that `*` will modify the `box-model` for all the elements, so you
>   can also use `ul` or a `class` name if you want to alter the box model
>   for specific elements only.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrv0mpsb/)

---

Or you need to reset the default <sup>Refer #1(end of my answer)</sup> `padding` of `ul` element

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrv0mpsb/1/) (Note that the bullet is no more there, so ...)

Nudge `li` using `margin`

```
ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrv0mpsb/2/)

Or you can use `list-style-position: inside;` on `ul` element.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mrv0mpsb/3/)

> Note: Using `list-style-position` does have a down side if you have
>   multiple lines, which will result in line wrapping below your bullet
>   point so go ahead with `margin-left`, too many things I can cover here
>   but don't want to deviate from my actual answer.

---

**#1 Where did the `padding` came from?**

Each browser has it's own default stylesheet which we also call as user agent stylesheet. This stylesheet is applied when the web page has no other styles defined. So each browser has it's own styles and may vary and hence we use `reset.css` or `normalize.css` or a handy star declaration to reset styles like

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* alters box model */
}
```

Comment: I was writing mine until saw this wonderful answer, I'd also add the reason of having left padding by default on the ul and ol tags.

Comment: @Pangloss I was already in the middle of writing the reason for that when you commented or you actually saw my old outdated answer (after I updated) :p, and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the box models for both the `<ul>` and `<div>`, it is clear that the `<ul>` has an extra left-padding. This *default* padding comes from the user agent's default style sheet - which may vary from browser to browser.

A `padding: 0` style on the `<ul>` should fix it. You may also want to consider using [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which renders all elements more consistently across various browsers.

**Box model for the `<ul>`**

[image: UL's box model]

**Box model for the `<div>`**

[image: Box model for the <code><div></code>]

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Foo
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is `padding-left` on `ul` elements by default.
2. Remove padding from `ul` or set `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Foo
</div>
<ul>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Foo
</div>
<ul>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The UL has padding to indent it. If you set the padding to 0 on the UL they will both be the same width.

Here's another post that explains in detail how to fix it

[Floating two 50% width divs with a 10px margin between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164288/floating-two-50-width-divs-with-a-10px-margin-between)